What is the best way to show a user that they no longer qualify for an item?
I am working on a mobile app with coupons at various brands. Each coupon has a defined target audience, and users that fall into that audience based on their user attributes will see the coupon. Users that do not fall into the target audience will not see the coupon. For example:
Show coupon to users that have made a purchase at [BRAND] in the last 6 months. Coupon expires on Dec 31, 2024.
Let's say hypothetically a user falls into this category because their last purchase at the brand was Jan 1st, and today is July 1st. They see the coupon and plan to go shop at the brand in a few days. However, on July 5th, they would no longer fall into this category because it's been more than 6 months since their last purchase.
The coupon qualifications will be stated in the terms & conditions, however, what is the best way to display this in the UI so that users have context on what coupons they qualify for and which ones they no longer qualify for? It seems like a bad user experience if the coupon suddenly disappears from the app. Especially if the user saw that the coupon doesn't expire until Dec 31st, they're left wondering why they don't see the coupon anymore.
Should this follow a similar pattern to "out of stock" or "sold out" items where the item has a tag and the image opacity lightened? Attached is an example of a product list with sold out items


Any ideas or examples of apps that do this well is much appreciated!

What about adding the expiring date? Many apps do that.

Putting myself in you User Scenario of seeing the coupon on July 1st then not seeing it again on July 5th when I went to purchase, I would have wanted to know the timeline expiration when I first saw the coupon.
There would be both user benefits and a marketing/sales benefits (scarcity/while supplies last/get it while you can) in exposing an offer/discount expiry end date in your UI. Let users know the timeframe is limited, not letting them see they greyed out coupon after they missed it. It's similar to the philosophy of Usability Heuristic #5, only dealing with missed-offer prevention instead of Error Prevention.
What I can see of your UI doesn't offer lots of room for such info. A few options you could consider:

Offer countdown on each coupon tile: probably too crowded and confusing
Offer countdown when users click into a coupon: won't fully expose to users scrolling that the deal is limited
Red timer icon (or something) on coupon tiles w/ notification snackbar: Snackbar text could be something like "You have coupons available that expire in the next week" and icon + colouring between the coupon tiles and snackbar communicates urgency without having to add times all over the place.

I would definitely try to focus my UX efforts on letting users know about the time limitations before they missed out, not letting users know what they've missed out on.

Great points! This approach would work if we could define a personalized coupon expiration date for the individual user based on their buying behavior. However, the challenge I have is each coupon has a standard expiration date defined by the brand. Let's say the coupon expiration date in this example is Dec 31, 2024. So in the background, the user no longer qualifies for this coupon on July 5th, but the actual coupon expiration displayed is Dec 31st.

If the coupon will no longer be available to users or they would no longer be able to see it, you have to have some form of "personalized coupon expiration". That's probably more relevant to your users, if they can't access a coupon after July 5th why would they care that it expires in December?
